# Looking for some Style error help in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've adapted a old VS from for JS but every I try to run it I get the following error:

> uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'style') of null

I've tried so many thing's and can't figure it out. It seems as though the page is not fully loaded before running the on load function.

I've tried pulling the function out of the onload and working it with the document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" function but it seem to never finish loading.

I've been at it for hours and hours and all over the internet and can't seem to figure it out.

All I'm looking for is when the page loads it hide's the selection fields that are not suppose to be shown in the HideStaff() function.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Select the Owner</title>
</head>
<script src="\\kgnobflst01\obind_config$\HTMLForms\jquery1.12.4\jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="\\kgnobflst01\obind_config$\HTMLForms\jquery1.12.4\jquery-ui-1.12.1\jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <form name="myform" method="POST">
    <table id="Maintbl" width="500" CELLSPACING=0>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap colspan="2"><strong><big>Select the Owner(s)</big></strong></td><br><br>
      </tr>

      <div>
        <tr>
          <td nowrap colspan="2"><label name="Staff_Label" id="Staff_Label">New Staff Policy Owner:</label>
            <!--            <label name="Testing_Label1" id="Testing_Label1">(Staff)</label> -->
            <select id="ddStaffOwner" name="OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-Staff_1" size="1"></select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>

      <!-- For The DE Queue -->
      <div>
        <tr>
          <td nowrap colspan="2"><label name="NonStaff_DEPI_Label" id="NonStaff_DEPI_Label">New Non-Staff Policy Owner:</label>
            <!--            <label name="Testing_Label2" id="Testing_Label2">(DEPI)</label> 
                This is for Data entry and RNM SR as well-->
            <select id="ddOBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-DE-PI" name="OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-DE-PI_1" size="1"></select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>

      <!-- For The UW Queue -->
      <div>
        <tr>
          <td nowrap colspan="2"><label name="NonStaff_UW_Label" id="NonStaff_UW_Label">New Non-Staff Policy Owner:</label>
            <!--            <label name="Testing_Label3" id="Testing_Label3">(UW)</label> -->
            <select id="ddOBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW-Only" name="OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW-Only_1" size="1"></select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>

      <!-- For The PI Queue -->
      <div>
        <tr>
          <td nowrap colspan="2"><label name="NonStaff_PI_Label" id="NonStaff_PI_Label">New Non-Staff Policy Owner:</label>
            <!--            <label name="Testing_Label4" id="Testing_Label4">(PI)</label> -->
            <select id="ddOBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-PI" name="OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-PI_1" size="1"></select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>

      <!-- For The RNM Queue -->
      <div>
        <td nowrap colspan="2"><label name="NonStaff_UWRNM_Label" id="NonStaff_UWRNM_Label">New Non-Staff Policy Owner:</label>
          <!--          <label name="Testing_Label5" id="Testing_Label5">(RNMUW)</label> -->
          <select id="OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW" name="OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW_1" size="1"></select>
        </td>
        </tr>
      </div>

    </table>
    <br>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
        <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit" name="OBBtn_Yes" onclick="UpdateProperties()">
        <input type=submit id=OBBtn_No name=OBBtn_No value="Cancel" />
      </td>

    </tr>
    <br><br>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="OB_WFProperty_PBStaffExists_1" id="OB_WFProperty_PBStaffExists_1" /></td><br>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffExists_1" id="OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffExists_1" /></td><br>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="OB_WFProperty_PBStaffName_1" id="OB_WFProperty_PBStaffName_1" value="" /></td><br>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffName_1" id="OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffName_1" value="" /></td><br>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="OB_WFProperty_PBWFLifeCycle_1" id="OB_WFProperty_PBWFLifeCycle_1" value="" /></td><br>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1" id="OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1" value="" /></td><br>
    </tr>

  </form>


  <script language=javascript>
    window.onload = HideStaff();

    function HideStaff() {

      if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Review New Mail (SR)") {
        var currentqueue = "SR";
      } else if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Unreviewed New Mail - Unknown") {
        var currentqueue = "SR";
      } else if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Unreviewed New Mail") {
        var currentqueue = "SR";
      } else if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Review New Mail (UW)") {
        var currentqueue = "UW";
      } else if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Unreviewed UW New Mail - Unknown") {
        var currentqueue = "UW";
      } else if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Unreviewed UW New Mail") {
        var currentqueue = "UW";
      } else {
        var currentqueue = "NA";
      }

      var pBtaffExists = myform.OB_WFProperty_PBStaffExists_1.value;
      var pBNonStaffExists = myform.OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffExists_1.value;
      var pBWFLifeCycle = myform.OB_WFProperty_PBWFLifeCycle_1.value;
      var pBWFQueue = myform.OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1.value;

      console.log(currentqueue + "," + pBtaffExists + "," + pBNonStaffExists + "," + pBWFLifeCycle + "," + pBWFQueue)

      if (pBtaffExists == "TRUE") {
        document.getElementById('OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-Staff_1').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('Staff_Label').style.visibility = 'visible';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-Staff_1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('Staff_Label').style.display = 'none';
      }

      if ((pBNonStaffExists == "TRUE") && (pBWFLifeCycle == "DE - Data Entry - Unity")) {
        document.getElementById('OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-DE-PI_1').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('NonStaff_DEPI_Label').style.visibility = 'visible';
      } else if ((pBNonStaffExists == "TRUE") && (pBWFLifeCycle == "RNM - Review New Mail - Unity") && (currentqueue == "SR")) {
        document.getElementById('OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-DE-PI_1').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('NonStaff_DEPI_Label').style.visibility = 'visible';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-DE-PI_1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('NonStaff_DEPI_Label').style.display = 'none';
      }

      if ((pBNonStaffExists == "TRUE") && (pBWFLifeCycle == "UW - Underwriting - Unity")) {
        document.getElementById('OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW-Only_1').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('NonStaff_UW_Label').style.visibility = 'visible';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW-Only_1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('NonStaff_UW_Label').style.display = 'none';
      }

      if ((pBNonStaffExists == "TRUE") && (pBWFLifeCycle == "RNM - Review New Mail - Unity") && (currentqueue == "UW")) {
        document.getElementById('OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW_1').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('NonStaff_UWRNM_Label').style.visibility = 'visible';
      } else {
        document.getElementById("OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW_1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('NonStaff_UWRNM_Label').style.display = 'none';
      }

      if ((pBNonStaffExists == "TRUE") && (pBWFLifeCycle == "PI - Policy Issue - Unity")) {
        document.getElementById('OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-PI_1').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('NonStaff_PI_Label').style.visibility = 'visible';
      } else {
        document.getElementById("OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-PI_1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('NonStaff_PI_Label').style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function UpdateProperties() {

      if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Review New Mail (SR)") {
        var currentqueue = "SR";
      }

      if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Unreviewed New Mail - Unknown") {
        var currentqueue = "SR";
      }

      if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Unreviewed New Mail") {
        var currentqueue = "SR";
      }

      if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Review New Mail (UW)") {
        var currentqueue = "UW";
      }

      if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Unreviewed UW New Mail - Unknown") {
        var currentqueue = "UW";
      }

      if (document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value == "RNM - Unreviewed UW New Mail") {
        var currentqueue = "UW";
      }

      if (myform.OB_WFProperty_PBStaffExists_1.value == "TRUE") {
        var dd1 = document.getElementById("ddStaffOwner");
        var value1 = dd1.options[dd1.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBStaffName_1").value = value1;
      }

      if ((myform.OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffExists_1.value == "TRUE") && (myform.OB_WFProperty_PBWFLifeCycle_1.value == "DE - Data Entry - Unity")) {
        var dd2 = document.getElementById("ddOBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-DE-PI");
        var value2 = dd2.options[dd2.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffName_1").value = value2;
      }

      if ((myform.OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffExists_1.value == "TRUE") && (myform.OB_WFProperty_PBWFLifeCycle_1.value == "UW - Underwriting - Unity")) {
        var dd3 = document.getElementById("ddOBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW-Only");
        var value3 = dd3.options[dd3.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffName_1").value = value3;
      }

      if ((myform.OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffExists_1.value == "TRUE") && (myform.OB_WFProperty_PBWFLifeCycle_1.value == "PI - Policy Issue - Unity")) {
        var dd4 = document.getElementById("ddOBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-PI");
        var value4 = dd4.options[dd4.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffName_1").value = value4;
      }

      if ((myform.OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffExists_1.value == "TRUE") && (myform.OB_WFProperty_PBWFLifeCycle_1.value == "RNM - Review New Mail - Unity") && (currentqueue == "SR")) {
        var dd5 = document.getElementById("ddOBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-DE-PI");
        var value5 = dd5.options[dd5.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffName_1").value = value5;
      }

      if ((myform.OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffExists_1.value == "TRUE") && (myform.OB_WFProperty_PBWFLifeCycle_1.value == "RNM - Review New Mail - Unity") && (currentqueue == "UW")) {
        var dd6 = document.getElementById("OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW");
        var value6 = dd6.options[dd6.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffName_1").value = value6;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `id="ddStaffOwner" name="OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-Staff_1"` - change the getElementById. Only IE would find a name by ID

Answer (score 2):

1. `id="ddStaffOwner" name="OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-Staff_1"` - change the ID to match the name. Only IE would find a name by ID
2. You do not need any jQuery libraries for the code you showed.
3. Use eventListeners instead of onclick and make sure those elements have IDs
4. Please run the HTML through the validator at https://validator.w3.org/ - for example do not have script tags between head and body. Also use

   ```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
   ```

before your title

Your code is VERY non-dry. Here is an attempt to make it less so.

I changed to .hidden instead of .style.display for readability and simplicity

The code is not fully tested since I do not have the select values.

```js
const getCurrentQueue = (wfQueueValue) => {
  switch (wfQueueValue) {
    case "RNM - Review New Mail (SR)":
    case "RNM - Unreviewed New Mail - Unknown":
    case "RNM - Unreviewed New Mail":
      return "SR";
    case "RNM - Review New Mail (UW)":
    case "RNM - Unreviewed UW New Mail - Unknown":
    case "RNM - Unreviewed UW New Mail":
      return "UW";
    default:
      return "NA";
  }
};


const updateProperties = (currentqueue, pBtaffExists, pBNonStaffExists, pBWFLifeCycle) => {
  if (pBtaffExists === "TRUE") {
    const ddStaff = document.getElementById("ddStaffOwner");
    document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBStaffName_1").value = ddStaff.options[ddStaff.selectedIndex].text;
  }

  let ddNonStaffId;
  switch (pBWFLifeCycle) {
    case "DE - Data Entry - Unity":
      ddNonStaffId = "ddOBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-DE-PI";
      break;
    case "UW - Underwriting - Unity":
      ddNonStaffId = "ddOBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW-Only";
      break;
    case "PI - Policy Issue - Unity":
      ddNonStaffId = "ddOBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-PI";
      break;
    case "RNM - Review New Mail - Unity":
      ddNonStaffId = currentqueue === "SR" ? "ddOBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-DE-PI" :
        currentqueue === "UW" ? "OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW" :
        null;
      break;
    default:
      ddNonStaffId = null;
  }

  if (pBNonStaffExists === "TRUE" && ddNonStaffId) {
    const ddNonStaff = document.getElementById(ddNonStaffId);
    document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffName_1").value = ddNonStaff.options[ddNonStaff.selectedIndex].text;
  }
};

const updateVisibility = (currentqueue, pBtaffExists, pBNonStaffExists, pBWFLifeCycle) => {

  let dropdownId;
  switch (pBWFLifeCycle) {
    case "DE - Data Entry - Unity":
    case "RNM - Review New Mail - Unity" && currentqueue === "SR":
      dropdownId = 'OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-DE-PI_1';
      break;
    case "UW - Underwriting - Unity":
      dropdownId = 'OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW-Only_1';
      break;
    case "RNM - Review New Mail - Unity" && currentqueue === "UW":
      dropdownId = 'OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-UW_1';
      break;
    case "PI - Policy Issue - Unity":
      dropdownId = 'OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-PI_1';
      break;
    default:
      dropdownId = null;
  }

  if (dropdownId) {
    document.getElementById(dropdownId).hidden = pBNonStaffExists !== "TRUE";
    document.getElementById(dropdownId + '_Label').hidden = pBNonStaffExists !== "TRUE";
  }
  document.getElementById('OBDataset_DS-NB-GetUsers-Staff_1').hidden = pBtaffExists !== "TRUE";
  document.getElementById('Staff_Label').hidden = pBtaffExists !== "TRUE";

};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const wfQueueValue = document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFQueue_1").value;
  const currentqueue = getCurrentQueue(wfQueueValue);
  const pBtaffExists = document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBStaffExists_1").value;
  const pBNonStaffExists = document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBNonStaffExists_1").value;
  const pBWFLifeCycle = document.getElementById("OB_WFProperty_PBWFLifeCycle_1").value;

  updateProperties(currentqueue, pBtaffExists, pBNonStaffExists, pBWFLifeCycle);
  updateVisibility(currentqueue, pBtaffExists, pBNonStaffExists, pBWFLifeCycle);
});

<!-- end snippet -->
```